# R - Metafor package–calculate and display odds ratio instead of log odds ratio

Tags: r, metafor

I'm essentially looking to produce my forest plot using the metafor package. It currently works extremely well, except for the fact that it produces the log odds ratio, while I want the pure odds ratio itself. Is there a simple way to do so within the metafor code?

```
#Metafor library
library(metafor)

#ReadXL library to import excel sheet
library(readxl)

#Name the data sheet from the excel file
abcd<- read_excel("analysis.xlsx")

#View the data sheet with view(abcd)

dpi=600    #pixels per square inch
tiff("metaor.tif", width=6*dpi, height=5*dpi, res=dpi)

#This below measures with risk ratios. If you want to measure odds ratios, use argument measure=OR
returnop <- escalc(measure="OR", ai=op_return_OR, bi=op_no_return_OR, ci=ip_return_OR, di=ip_no_return_OR, data=ACDF)

#Generate a Random Effects Model
REmodel<-rma(yi=yi, vi=vi, data=returnop, slab=paste(Author, Year, sep=", "), method="REML")

#Generate a forest plot of the data
forest(REmodel, xlim=c(-17, 6),
       ylim=c(-1, 10),
       ilab=cbind(abcd$op_return_OR, abcd$op_no_return_OR, abcd$ip_return_OR, 
                  abcd$ip_no_return_OR),
       ilab.xpos=c(-10,-8.4,-6.6,-4.9), cex=.75,
       psize=1)

### add column headings to the plot
text(c(-10,-8.4,-6.6,-4.9), 8.5, c("Return+", "Return-", "Return+", "Return-"), 
     cex = 0.65)
text(c(-9.25,-5.75),     9.5, c("Outpatient", "Inpatient"))
text(-17,                8.5, "Study",     pos=4)
text(6,                  8.5, "Log Odds Ratio [95% CI]", pos=2)


dev.off()
```

Appreciate the help, all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the `escalc` function:

> The options for the ‘measure’ argument are then:
>
> ```
>        • ‘"RR"’ for the _log risk ratio_.
>
>        • ‘"OR"’ for the _log odds ratio_.
>
>        • ‘"RD"’ for the _risk difference_.
>
>        • ‘"AS"’ for the _arcsine square root transformed risk
>          difference_ (Rücker et al., 2009).
>
>        • ‘"PETO"’ for the _log odds ratio_ estimated with Peto's
>          method (Yusuf et al., 1985).
>
>
>      Note that the log is taken of the risk ratio and the odds
>      ratio, which makes these outcome measures symmetric around 0
>      and yields corresponding sampling distributions that are
>      closer to normality.
> ```

For this reason, I guess the answer to you question is no as there is no `measure` value that will give you pure odd ratio and all the analysis/figures using pure odds ratio (OR). If you want pure OR my guess you have to use `exp()`, for instance`exp(returnop$yi)` to get the odd ratio and a couple of similar calculus to have all the results expressed in pure odd ratio. There might be another way I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing the `forest()` function, add the `"atransf = exp"` parameter.
That should do it.

```
"forest(REmodel, xlim=c(-17, 6), ylim=c(-1, 10), 
ilab=cbind(ACDF$op_return_OR, ACDF$op_no_return_OR, ACDF$ip_return_OR, 
ACDF$ip_no_return_OR), ilab.xpos=c(-10,-8.4,-6.6,-4.9), cex=.75, 
psize=1, atransf="exp")"
```

Let me know if it works and if you have any other question!